# jQuery.detach and animate out of element

Tags: jquery, css

So, I want to 'pop' out an element which is a child of it's parent-container, by .detach()-ing it from the parent, then position it over its original coordinates, then animate it outside the parent.

This works now, if you click on the 'POP' button in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TrySpace/y5WGR/20/).

This is mainly because of the line:

```
childy.css({ position: 'absolute' });
```

Although, I don't totally get why it needs to  be absolute, I rather have a solution where I can keep that intact, and don't have to revert it to 'relative' if I pop it back inside a div.

However, the 'PIP' button, should do the same, but keep it inside the parent, just for testing, but I noticed that it skips down, before the animate, probably because the margins and paddings are not calculated with `.position();`

Any ways to calculate the padding and margins of the element? I've tried some methods like .outerWidth, and .css("padding-top") but I can't get it to work.

Comment: FYI: You don't need `detach()`. Use `remove()`. Only detach if you have stored `data()` that you want to keep.

Comment: @Johan FYI: I need detach(), because I have stored data() I want to keep.

Comment: Well, you aren't using it in your example. Good luck!